# Djnago Apps One Static Folder for all templates

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to use Static files (css, js ...) for all apps templates?

For example, I have a css file for all templates in different apps, should I place it to each templates folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a django project, you can store your templates at the root level. The root level is where you should put your global files and templates:

```
Project
-- manage.py
-- Project
-- -- views.py
-- -- models.py
-- -- static     <- here are your project wide static files
-- -- templates  <- here are your project wide templates
-- -- APP1
-- -- -- views.py
-- -- -- models.py
-- -- -- others
-- -- APP2
-- -- -- views.py
-- -- -- models.py
-- -- -- others
```

Those templates and static files are accessible in any of your applications.